# UWP Is there a way to animate the position and size of StackPanel when loading Page into a Frame?

Tags: xaml, animation, uwp

I have a Button and a Menu inside a StackPanel with horizontal orientation and centered horizontally and Vertically. To the right of the button there's an empty Panel. When the Button gets clicked, a Page is loaded inside the Panel. The thing is that the Button moves to the left automatically so every keeps centered. I was wondering if there's a way that the movement of the button gets animated instead of just appearing in the final position.

Here's the code.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="VentanaPrincipal" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

    <StackPanel x:Name="MenuPrincipal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Transparent" Stroke="#B12025" StrokeThickness="2"/>
            <Ellipse Width="85" Height="85" Fill="#eeeeee"/>
        </Grid>
        <TextBlock
                    Margin="0,10,0,0"
                    Text="Nombre Completo"
                    FontWeight="SemiBold"
                    FontSize="14"
                    Foreground="#818181"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock
                    Text="Puesto"
                    FontWeight="SemiBold"
                    FontSize="12"
                    Foreground="#B8B8B8"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button Margin="0,30,0,20" Content="Registrar Usuario" Style="{StaticResource BotonUsuarioNuevo}" Click="RegistrarUsuario_Click"/>
        <Grid Width="220" Padding="0,10,0,0">
            <Border Margin="0,-10,0,0" Width="180" Height="270" BorderBrush="#CCCFDB" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="15"/>
            <Border Width="180" Margin="0,80,0,0" BorderBrush="#CCCFDB" Height="2" BorderThickness="2"/>
            <Border Width="180" Margin="0,-100,0,0" BorderBrush="#CCCFDB" Height="2" BorderThickness="2"/>
            <Border Margin="0,-10,0,0" Height="270" BorderBrush="#CCCFDB" Width="2" BorderThickness="2"/>
            <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Secciones}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CustomGridViewItem}" Padding="10,10,0,0" Width="200" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Seccion">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind titulo}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
    <Frame x:Name="infoA"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: For your requirement, the better way is create connected animation for the navigate page, and this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/motion/connected-animation) is helpful.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Thank you so much for the information! but I was wondering if there's a way of doing that without having to change the main page. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few ways.

1: Apply RepositionThemeTransition to the `ChildrenTransitions` property of the Button's parent StackPanel. Any time any of the StackPanels children are moved, they will be animated to their new position.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="MenuPrincipal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <RepositionThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False" />
        </TransitionCollection>
    </StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
    ...
    <Button Margin="0,30,0,20" Content="Registrar Usuario" Style="{StaticResource BotonUsuarioNuevo}" Click="RegistrarUsuario_Click"/>
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

(This can be done with any panel, like Grid or Canvas, etc)

2: Apply reposition transition to Button. (Not entirely certain this works)

```
<Button Margin="0,30,0,20" Content="Registrar Usuario" Style="{StaticResource BotonUsuarioNuevo}" Click="RegistrarUsuario_Click">
    <Button.Transitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <RepositionThemeTransition />
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Button.Transitions>
</Button>
```

3. Apply a Composition Offset animation to the Button (or any other element). Any layout position change applied to the target element by it's parent will run the  animation. This animation you can actually customise the duration and the easing function used if desired.

```
 <Button Loaded="SetReposition" Margin="0,30,0,20" Content="Registrar Usuario" Style="{StaticResource BotonUsuarioNuevo}" Click="RegistrarUsuario_Click"/>
```

```
public void SetReposition(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    UIElement e = (UIElement)sender;
    Visual v = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(e);

    var o = v.Compositor.CreateVector3KeyFrameAnimation();
    o.Target = nameof(Visual.Offset);
    o.InsertExpressionKeyFrame(0, "this.StartingValue");
    o.InsertExpressionKeyFrame(1, "this.FinalValue");
    o.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3);

    var collection = v.Compositor.CreateImplicitAnimationCollection();
    collection.Add(nameof(Visual.Offset), o);

    v.ImplicitAnimations = collection;
}
```